# How does ORDER BY work with single-value expressions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a problem with `order by`. We know that if we give integer in order by then it orders via index of column. When I use it this way every time I execute query, I get same result, which is correct.

But when I make this value the result of an expression (I mean I use a expression which *always* evaluates to 1), then I get 3 possible combinations of result when I execute it.

So for same value which is static, same result; but for same value which is an evaluated expression, different results.

Below is the example of query which I am referring to:

```
SELECT SomeColumns, (rand()* 10) as rand
FROM TableName
ORDER BY (if ((rand in (1) ), 1,1))
LIMIT 0 , 6
```

The above query gives three possible result sets.

Comment: Question is : Why is it this way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ORDER BY`'s [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) is:

```
ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position} [ASC | DESC], ...
```

Although the following would appear to the human-eye to be equivalent:

```
ORDER BY 1
ORDER BY (if ((rand in (1) ), 1,1))
```

they are not.

- The first one sorts by the `1`st column's data, as it's an integer with value `1`.
- The second one, although it evaluates to `1`, is not an integer but an expression and, as such, a *different* sorting mechanism is invoked. For each row, the expression `1` is evaluated and used to determine the row's position; because your expression actually doesn't refer to row data at all, your results will be completely unpredictable.

  Whether you'll get the table's "natural order" (that is, the physical ordering that happens to be present underneath the relational abstractions) or some random-looking order that the `ORDER BY` created I couldn't say, but it also doesn't matter.

Usually you'd write something like this for an expression:

```
ORDER BY `col` % 6
```

... i.e. something that references data.

Comment: The result can be unpredictable for first time, but not every time. I mean if I use no order by, then also the ordering is unpredictable, but still we get same ordering everytime if we execute same query......

Comment: @viv: My point is that you cannot rely on that. The result _is_ unpredictable, even if that unpredictability happens to yield similar results several times in a row. In this case it may be query caching doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) statement syntax; `ORDER BY` clause is defined as:

> ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}

Later on this page it is mentioned:

> Column positions are integers and begin with 1

Sort by column position works as expected when it is specified as an integer *literal*. In your case, `ORDER BY (if ((rand in (1) ), 1,1))` is an expression, not a column position. It works as follows:

- The `rand` column is added to all rows that contains values between 0.0 and 9.9999...
- The expression `if(rand in (1), 1, 1)` is evaluated for each row as follows:

  - The sub-expression `rand in (1)` almost always returns false because there the chances of the `rand` column being exactly 1 are very, very, very low
  - Depending on the previous expression the `IF` condition evaluates to 1 or 1 (perhaps it was a typo in your code)
  - The whole expression evaluates to `1` for each row
- Since the expression in `ORDER BY` clause yields `1` for each row, the rows will not be sorted

Comment: But still the rows are sorted somehow, and it's not a natural order, and it also changes with consecutive runs of the query.

Comment: Aha. It took me a moment, but I get it now. This is sorting by a factor that has no correlation with the actual data (hence apparently random results), but misleading because to the human-eye it appears to be an integer (after evaluation) column sort, rather than the expression sort which is a completely unrelated mechanism

Comment: @Mchl: not sure. I tested the query with dummy data and rows were always sorted the same way no matter how many passes I ran.

Comment: I, on the other hand, got 3 or 4 sets of rows that would be selected. Apparently `rand()` is somehow affecting the results, because when it's removed from column list, the results come back in natural order.

Comment: @Mchl: I expect you're seeing the results of some internal mechanism. You're not specifying any order with relation to the data, so anything can happen.

Comment: Yeah... I'm thinking MySQL might be creating a temporary table with who-knows-what indexes.

Comment: @viv: Why do you "need to know"?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit : May be it can help me anytime in future. Actually I was thinking how "order by rand()" works, from there i tried this query.....

Comment: @Salman A : Well i think, it should not be random everytime, there is something else working. Same query with no ordering gives same ordering every time

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER BY (if ((rand in (1) ), 1,1))
```

it ordered your result set based on the expression. for dynamic value it also reordered based on your `order by` expression